# Set axes min/max for flutter_charts

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a bar chart using flutter_charts. I have altered the bar chart to use double values for its x-axis, but I need to manipulate the axes in two specific ways:

1. The y-axis must always be from 0 to 200, regardless of whether or not the data reaches 10
2. The x-axis has ticks every value of 2 (if the data spans from an x-axis of 0 to 11, the ticks should be 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)

How would I go about doing that?

Sample code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  MyHomePage(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [LineChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory MyHomePage.withSampleData() {
    return new MyHomePage(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100, horizontal: 24),
      child: new charts.NumericComboChart(seriesList,
          animate: animate,
          // Configure the default renderer as a line renderer. This will be used
          // for any series that does not define a rendererIdKey.
          defaultRenderer: new charts.LineRendererConfig(),
          // Custom renderer configuration for the bar series.
          customSeriesRenderers: [
            new charts.BarRendererConfig(
                // ID used to link series to this renderer.
                customRendererId: 'customBar')
          ]),
    );
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, double>> _createSampleData() {
    final desktopSalesData = [
      new LinearSales(0, 5),
      new LinearSales(2, 25),
      new LinearSales(5, 100),
      new LinearSales(10, 75),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, double>(
        id: 'Desktop',
        colorFn: (_, __) => charts.MaterialPalette.blue.shadeDefault,
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: desktopSalesData,
      )
        // Configure our custom bar renderer for this series.
        ..setAttribute(charts.rendererIdKey, 'customBar'),
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample linear data type.
class LinearSales {
  final double year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a workaround for my first issue and solve my second issue. I will detail my steps in case someone in the future needs help with charts_flutter:

1. I couldn't figure out if there were any properties to manipulate in order to set the axes limits. However, since my goal was to always set my chart's vertical axis to 10 and because I knew my measure values would never exceed 10, I worked around this by creating transparent data points with values of 10 so that the chart always reached 10. The relevant pieces of my code are below:

```
final yaxisLine = [
      new DistressLevel(distressLevelsOverTime[0].minutes, 10),
      new DistressLevel(distressLevelsOverTime.last.minutes, 10)
    ]; // Type of class DistressLevel, which has int minutes for domain and double anxiety level for measure

// Is always drawn at anxiety level 10
// Is not visible to user, but is used to insure axis always reaches anxiety of 10
      new charts.Series<DistressLevel, double>(
        id: 'axisLine',
        colorFn: (DistressLevel distress, __) =>
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.transparent),
        domainFn: (DistressLevel distress, _) => distress.minutes,
        measureFn: (DistressLevel distress, _) => distress.distressLevel,
        data: yaxisLine,
      )..setAttribute(charts.rendererIdKey, 'axisLine'),
```

2. Second part of my problem was very straight forward. You just need to add some property adjustments into the place where you are actually calling/drawing the chart widget

```
domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                                     
                                      showAxisLine: false,
                                      tickProviderSpec: new charts
                                              .BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(
                                          // Vertical axis every 2 ticks from 0 to 10
                                          dataIsInWholeNumbers: true,
                                          desiredTickCount: 6),
                                      renderSpec: charts.SmallTickRendererSpec(
                                        labelStyle: new charts.TextStyleSpec(
                                            color:
                                                charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(
                                                    Color(0xFF8ea5bb))),
                                      )),
```